# Custom CalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to display a `CalendarView` and then change backgound of certain blocks (of dates) red and certain blocks green. Now, I don't think I can do that in  default `CalendarView`.

So, I started googling about how to create a custom CalendarView and I came to know that creating a custom CalendarView is impossible. We have to use a `GridView`.

So, I just wanted to know that is that really true and if it is not then how should I go about making a custom CalendarView

Comment: That is true. My team make a calendar (ViewPager+GridViews').

Comment: Okay so I guess I'll have to go ahead and make a subclass of `GridView`. That's my only way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library available now known as [`ZCustomCalendar`](https://github.com/naishadhparmar/ZCustomCalendar) which allows you to define individual custom views for various types of dates.